# A variable to return a number once, then 0 afterwards

Tags: python

Changed the code so many times it doesn't even run now. I don't know what I'm doing to be frank.

Trying to make a user entered starting point for single use in a generator function and have it return 0 thereafter.

```
def selfDestruct(max=1):
    throwaway = 255              # enter manually  starting point 
    n = 0
    if n < max:
        n += 1
    elif n >= max:
         throwaway = 0
print(throwaway)
print(throwaway)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can already see a problem with this. First of all, you are trying to print a variable located inside of a function. This is not possible due to something called that function being local. Your local function `throwaway` is only available for use inside that defined `selfDestruct` function. Second, everytime you use a function, the variables inside of it are reset to the default. Meaning, once you run that function and it does `n += 1`, the next time you run it `n` will still equal 0. What I suggest is this:

```
n = 0

def selfDestruct(max=1):
    throwaway = 255       
    global n
    if n < max:
      n += 1
    elif n >= max:
      throwaway = 0
    return throwaway
      
print(selfDestruct())
print(selfDestruct())
```

I made the variable `n` outside the function so its scope is the entire script. Meaning, it won't be reset like before. Inside the function `selfDestruct` I added the line `global n`. This basically makes it so that when the function is called, it is able to edit the variable `n` outside of it. Additionally, I added `return throwaway` which is something you need if you want your function to return a value. Finally, I switched your `print` statement with `print(selfDestruct())` which calls the function. If you do not know what calling a function means, then I suggest searching it up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your original code was really trying to do, but "generator function that generates up to a given value, then produces `0` afterwards" is pretty easy:

```
from itertools import repeat

def selfDestruct(max=1):
    yield from range(max)  # Use max + 1 if it should produce max itself
    yield from repeat(0)   # We finished yielding the range, now we yield 0 forever

    # Or as a one-liner that doesn't even require an actual generator function,
    # add chain to the imports from itertools and just do:
    return chain(range(max), repeat(0))
```

If you don't want to use `range` or `itertools.repeat` it's not much harder:

```
def selfDestruct(max=1):
    n = 0
    while n < max:  # <= max to include max itself
        yield n
        n += 1
    while True:     # Infinite loop yielding 0 forever
        yield 0
```

You use it with a standard `for` construct, though you'll need `break` or `itertools.islice` involved to prevent the generator from continuing forever:

```
lasti = None
for i in selfDestruct(10):
    print(i)
    if lasti == i:
        break  # See the same number twice in a row (the trailing zeroes) and we stop
    lasti = i
```